# How to emit socket data to a particular client(based on deviceId) in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, socket.io

I've a system which has many templates. Templates have multiple sensors associated to it. Each sensor sends the data to the server and stores in the database. Each sensor has a unique deviceId. And the data stores in to the respective template collection in Mongo Database.

For ex, there are two devices(sbdth11-001,sbdth11-002) and "sbdth11-001" sending data while "sbdth11-002" is kept idle. On the front-end side when I see the grid of "sbdth11-001", I'm getting the data. But when I see the grid of "sbdth11-002", it's getting the data of "sbdth11-001". That means server-socket emitting data to all clients connected to it. Can anyone help in solving this. Please have a look at my code.

**SERVER SIDE**
**Server.JS**

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
global.io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
//console.log('a user connected');
});
```

**Routes.JS**

```
router.post("/upload/device/data/:tempId", TemplateController.AddDeviceData);
```

**TemplateController.JS**

```
AddDeviceData:async function(req, res){
    let err, deviceLog;

    [err, deviceLog]=await to(TemplateService.AddDeviceLogs(req.params.tempId, req.body));
    if(err) return res.serverError(err.message);
    if(deviceLog&&deviceLog!==false){
        return res.ok(deviceLog);
    }else{
        res.badRequest("Sorry cannot add Device log data");
    }
}
```

**TemplateService.JS**

```
AddDeviceLogs:async function(templateId, payload){
    let err, deviceData;

    payload.template=templateId;
    payload.entryDayTime=new Date();
    const myCollection=templateId;
    [err, deviceData]=await to(mongoose.connection.db.collection(myCollection).insert(payload));
    if(err) TE(err.message, true);
    //Socket emit code begin
    if(deviceData){
        let err,singleDeviceData,allDevicesData;;

        [err,singleDeviceData]= await to(this.displayLogs(templateId,payload.deviceId));
        [err,allDevicesData] = await to(this.displayLogs(templateId));
        if(err) io.emit('socketError', err.message);
        io.emit('singleDeviceData',singleDeviceData); //Has to emit the data to 
                    //the device of template whose IDs matches 
                    //with the IDs in this.displayLogs(templateId,payload.deviceId) 
        io.emit('allDevicesData',allDevicesData);//Has to emit the data to 
                    //the template whose ID matches 
                    //with the ID in this.displayLogs(templateId)
    }
    //Socket emit code end
    return (deviceData)? deviceData.result:false;
}
```

**GRID OF DEVICE sbdth11-001**
[image]
**GRID OF DEVICE sbdth11-002**
[image]

Both the grids getting the same data. If a device is not sending any data, it should render nothing in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution. We just need to send the deviceId along with socket emit event to the client-socket.

Here in my usecase, I've many devices in a template. Template ID is unique and device IDs in template should be unique. But one deviceId can be used multiple times in different templates keeping in mind that deviceId should be unique at template level.

Here is the code.

**Server Code(Node.JS)**

```
io.emit(`singleDeviceData${templateId}${payload.deviceId}`,singleDeviceData); //Emitting the device data of a template

io.emit(`allDevicesData${templateId}`,allDevicesData); //Emitting the data of all devices(template)
```

On front-end side, we need to compare the deviceId and templateId before rendering the data into the grid.

We emit the event like, `singleDeviceData566567586Device-1`. Here `singleDeviceData` is the event name, `566567586` is the templateId and `Device-1` is the deviceId.

So on client-side, on listening `singleDeviceData` event, we compare `566567586` and `Device-1` with the templateId and deviceId of web page we currently opened on browser. If both are same, then it renders the data and as data kept inserting into the DB, it updates continuously. Else, displays what should be displayed on this page and data won't be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Console log this `socket` variable. It should have an ID. Save this ID.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
//console.log('a user connected');
});
```

To emit only to this client:

```
  io.to(`${socketId}`).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I've multiple devices sending data continuously right now. How could I emit the data sent by a device to itself to be rendered in the front-end?

Comment: If you are using rooms, then `io.in('NameOfTheRomm').emit('singleDeviceData',singleDeviceData);`

Comment: Or... You can add another `to()`  `io.to(`${socketId}`).to(`${myId}`).emit('hey', 'I just met you');`

Comment: When a user connect you set a room for it like this `socket.join('NameOfRoom');` and then. You use this emit to send to everyone in that room, including the sender `io.in('NameOfTheRomm').emit('singleDeviceData',singleDeviceData);`